# Appium Android UiSelector for Sibling or Children Elements

Tags: android, ios, .net, appium

I'm using C# and Appium (specifically the nuget package version 5.0.0-rc.2), and I've got my test framework set up to resolve the locators for a page object class dynamically based on the active driver type.

Now, my actual question:

I've got a couple elements that I can only find via XPATH. Specifically some elements that are siblings or children. For example, I've got a modal that comes up with different syncing statuses.

[image: Cropped Screenshot of an Android app menu]

I use `//android.view.View[@resource-id="notesStatus"]/*` to locate the "notes status" label and the sync status boxes.
Then I use `//android.view.View[@resource-id="notesStatus"]/android.view.View/*` to get the two different sync status boxes.

```xml
...
<android.view.View index="15" package="com.package.app" class="android.view.View" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[549,798][1452,801]" displayed="true" hint="" />
<android.view.View index="16" package="com.package.app" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="notesStatus" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[549,798][1452,864]" displayed="true" hint="">
  <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.package.app" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Notes Status" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[573,814][730,846]" displayed="true" hint="" />
  <android.view.View index="1" package="com.package.app" class="android.view.View" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[1209,813][1428,849]" displayed="true" hint="">
    <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.package.app" class="android.widget.TextView" text="0 Unsynced" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[1209,813][1338,849]" displayed="true" hint="" />
    <android.widget.TextView index="1" package="com.package.app" class="android.widget.TextView" text="0 Failed" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[1335,813][1428,849]" displayed="true" hint="" />
  </android.view.View>
</android.view.View>
...
```

**Is it possible to use Android's UiSelector to get these child and sibling elements instead of XPath?** I've tried a couple different things, but they only get, for example, the PAIR of the sync status boxes, not the individual boxes.

example UiSelector: `new UiSelector().className("android.view.View").resourceId("notesStatus").childSelector(new UiSelector().className("android.view.View"))`

Full background on why I want to be able to use UiSelector and not just stick with FindElementsByXpath--

The page object class has a set of locators that are of the `MobileBy` type, and then when the test is run, the driver type is used to inject the appropriate IOS or Android `By` object.
So, if the driver is an IOS driver? It uses the `ByIosUIAutomation` object for that locator.
If the driver is an Android driver? It uses the `ByAndroidUIAutomator` object for that locator.
This is so I don't have to have to keep fully separate page objects for IOS *and* Android, I just have to maintain separate locator sets for each page object, and do some conditionals on some of my page object class methods.